# Click function fails to get id

Tags: jquery

The problem I have could arise due to many causes so, first the scenario. I am rebuilding a navigation interface for a roughly 12 year old news archive system. So, some legacy issues. I am using a combo of php and jquery.
[image]
Screen shot of the interface
DATA:
A flatfile structure...
dir - 2015
files: 4-1-2015.dat + 30-1-2015.dat + etc.
dir - 2014
files: - + etc.
with each *.dat file holding html for the newsletter of that date.

On the interface each Month-Day has its ID set according to the file structure with common class="linky" eg: id="4-1-2015" = day-month-year {.dat added later}

PHP TO BUILD AN ARRAY of files; snip below [var = listing]

```
[2015] => Array
[1] => Array ~january
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 30
[2] => Array ~ february
    [0] => 18
[3] => Array
    [0] => 9 etc.
```

and, again, PHP to build the first screen.
The alert (see below) works fine for this.

THEN JQUERY...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
var dataArray = <?php echo json_encode($listing); ?>;  // the full array  
var yearArray = <?php echo json_encode($yearList); ?>; // just years  
var newDate = parseInt($("#navYear").text(), 10)-1;    

$.each(dataArray[$("#navYear").text()], function(index, days) { // index=Month value=Day  
dataArray[$("#navYear").text()][index].sort(function(a, b){return a-b}); // numerical order  
    dayings = days.toString().split(','); // monthLinks = [1] 4,19 [2] 4,18,26 [3] 20  
    for ( var d = 0; d <dayings.length; ++d ) {  
monListing = monListing+'<span class="linky" id="'+dayings[d]+'-'+index+'-'+newDate+'">'+monArray[index-1]+' '+dayings[d]+'</span>';  
    }  
    }); // end each...  
$(".linky").click(function() {  
    dataLink = $(this).attr("id");  
    // dataLink = this.id;  
    alert(dataLink);  
    });  
}); // end doc ready
```

As I mentioned, the PHP build yields an alert. The js does not.

[image]

FF inspector clearly shows the id as being set with intended class. But no alert.

I have tried pre-setting all monListing values as both integers and strings. eg.
var eachDay = parseInt(dayings[d], 10); or:
var eachDay = dayings[d].toString();

I tried changing the '-' to '_'
set id as 'asd'
multiple permutations of... what ever I could think might be wrong.

The solution eludes me!!
Is there anything clearly obvious to you here?
Even the most obscure of suggestions would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: when you click on the `linky` what you are getting?? I mean is it navigating inside your event??

Comment: declare variable : var dataLink = $(this).attr("id");

Comment: click linky has no result - no 'undefined' no empty alert box... nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems llike `.linky` is a dynamic element that you created with your code, so you need to use `.on` to enable `click` event:

```
 $("body").on('click', '.linky', function() {
```

Comment: YESssss! Very grateful for your incredibly prompt response... AND, a totally working solution. Easy when you know how. :))

Comment: marked.! I apologise for forgetting I don't come here so often... but am always happy when I do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `$(this).attr("id")` try just doing `$(this).id`.

Comment: As you might see I tried a plain 'this.id;' but will try your suggest. Thank you

Comment: Nope :( for some reason it screwed the 2015 level - which was working. Weird